# C# regex parse to pull photos from markdown?

Tags: c#, regex, markdown

Photos in markdown look like `![alt text](src)`. I'd like to parse a block of markdown, pulling all photo sources into an `IList<string>`.

I know regex is probably the answer, but it's like an ancient cryptic language to me... how would I go about parsing out all photos into an `IList<string>` using C#?

#### Example text

```
![](http://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/530402_10151620341829517_1993977231_n.jpg)
When I say "Japanese-Chinese" food I'm not referring to some new type of restaurant      serving both Japanese and Chinese food. This means the restaurant serves Chinese food   prepared for Japanese tastes.

![](http://sphotos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/385269_10151620364269517_1368819859_n.jpg)
This is **subuta** -- sweet and sour pork, this one photo showing the meal set (tenshoku in Japanese). It's one of many Chinese dishes this restaurant serves... and they have **A LOT**!
```

Comment: Can you give me some example text, to test against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, should work:

```
!\[.*?\]\(.*?\)
```

have a play here, to see how this works:

http://tinyurl.com/qxjqhcs

```
var matches = new Regex(@"!\[.*?\]\(.*?\)")
    .Matches(str)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 Great link. Looks like a very useful tool. [Best not to use URL shorteners though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/181221).

Comment: @Chris I think that's the only way you can link to this particular site! :(

Comment: This is almost what I want... this pulls the entire markdown... but I just want the image source part `between the ()`.

Comment: Nevermind... group 1 from the regex contains what I want. Thank you!